# extracting URIs from RDF/XML document through Jena Library

Tags: rdf, jena

I want to extarct all URIs from a RDF/XML document. Does converting RDF/XML into Model Class in Jena Library and then extract URIs(non null) of each subject,predicate and object for each statement of that [Model class](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/index.html) will work for me??

```
    Model read = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel().read(my_url);
    StmtIterator si;
    si = read.listStatements();
```

where url is the RDF/XML web document..

Answer (score 2):

As the [Javadoc](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Model.html#listStatements%28%29) says, `listStatements()` will list all of the statements - i.e. triples - in the model.

If you want to list *all* of the URI's, you need to consider where they occur in an RDF model. You may or may not want all of these. For given triple, T, consisting of a subject, predicate and object:

- The subject of T will have a URI, unless is it an anonymous resource (bNode)
- The predicate of T will have a URI
- The object of T will have a URI if it is a resource not a literal, and if it is not a bNode

So (untested code):

```
Set<String> uris = new HashSet<String>();
for (StmtIterator i = model.listStatements(); i.hasNext(); ) {
    Statement s = i.next();
    if (!s.getSubject().isAnon()) {
        uris.add( s.getSubject().getURI() );
    }
    uris.add( s.getPredicate().getURI() );
    if (s.getObject().isResource() && !s.getResource().isAnon()) {
        uris.add( s.getResource().getURI() );
    }
}
```